# How to specify os version when installing NVIDIA Container Toolkit

Tags: nvidia, docker, versions, lsb-release

I am trying to install the NVIDIA Container Toolkit. The command to set up the repository and specify the GPG key is:

```
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID) \
      && curl -fsSL https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/gpgkey | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg \
      && curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/$distribution/libnvidia-container.list | \
            sed 's#deb https://#deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg] https://#g' | \
            sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-toolkit.list
```

However, I do not have an `/etc/os-release` file. I expect that `/etc/os-release` is meant to provide information about my operating system (i.e. Ubuntu 20.04). I do have two files, which appear to have similar intent, but are not executable: `/usr/lib/os-release` and `/etc/debian` file.

The contents of `/usr/lib/os-release`  are:

```
$ cat /usr/lib/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

The contents of `/etc/debian_version` are:

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version 
bullseye/sid
```

Finally, if I execute `lsb_release -a`, I get:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

So, with what do I need to replace

```
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)
```

Comment: In my case, `/etc/os-release` is a link to `/usr/lib/os-release`. It doesn't have to be executable, just readable, because it is not executed. You can test that line works with `distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID) && echo $distribution`. If there is no link, create it, or use the original - `/usr/lib/os-release`.